# Node Cluster how do I fork only 1 instance of a given node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, so I have an API written in Nodejs that is clustered to make use of all the cores available using the 'cluster' module for a total of 4 child processes.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
```

I have a process ('remNodeProcess') which I need to fork only 1 instance of, i.e I don't want each worker node forking its own instance of 'remNodeProcess'. This 'remNodeProcess' does NOT need to be available to every child node. For this I'm trying to use the 'child-process' module.

```
const childProcess = require('child_process');
```

I've had a good read of Node Clusters and have been using them for a short while. Clustering is working as expected and I'm getting the desired results but I can't seem to figure out how to fork a single instance of a process. I only want 1 instance of this process in the cluster.

Here's the full code to cluster:

```
const setupWorkerThreadNodes = () => {

    // Get system CPUs
    let SYS_CORE_COUNT = require('os').cpus().length;

    // Read the Config Thread Configuration, if it exceeds the SYS_CORE_COUNT, set it to max usage, otherwise honour the Config
    let coreCount;
    if (webAppConfig.appConfig.nodeClusterConfiguration.mtMaxWorkerThreadCount) {
        coreCount = webAppConfig.appConfig.nodeClusterConfiguration.mtMaxWorkerThreadCount;
    } else if (webAppConfig.appConfig.nodeClusterConfiguration.mtMaxWorkerThreadCount > SYS_CORE_COUNT) {
        coreCount = SYS_CORE_COUNT;
    }

    logMsg(`NODE_MASTER PID: ${process.pid}`);
    console.log('NODE_CLUSTER Master is setting up Nodes... ');

    // For each Core, create a node and push it to the system cluster array
    for (let i = 0; i < coreCount; i++) {
        console.log(`NODE_CLUSTER Master is setting up Node [${i}/${coreCount}]... `);
        workers.push(cluster.fork({ WorkerName: `Worker${i}` }));

        // When a Worker responds to the Master, log the response
        workers[i].on('message', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });
    }

    // process is clustered on a core and process id is assigned
    cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is listening');
        logMsg(`CLUSTER_NODE Child opened. PID: ${worker.process.pid}`)
    });

    // If the Workers count matches the CoreCount, we've opened the correct amount of threads
    if (workers.length === coreCount) logMsg(`NODE_CLUSTER Array successfully established.`, 'info');

    // if any of the worker process dies then start a new one by simply forking another one
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
        logMsg(`CLUSTER_NODE Child terminated. PID: ${worker.process.pid}. Code: ${code}. Signal: ${signal}`)
        console.log('Starting a new worker');
        cluster.fork();
        workers.push(cluster.fork());
        // to receive messages from worker process
        workers[workers.length - 1].on('message', function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });
    });
};
```

I've tried the following:

```
if(cluster.isMaster){
   const remNodeProcess= childProcess.fork('./background_workers/remNode.js');
   remNodeProcess.send(pool, (err) => { console.log(err) })
}
```

When I run the API with this code, remNodeProcess does not open. If I use the following code (without the IF wrapper):

```
const remNodeProcess= childProcess.fork('./background_workers/remNode.js');
remNodeProcess.send(pool, (err) => { console.log(err) })
```

I get one remNodeProcess for every child.

How do I fork one instance of a given process? and can this be done from the Master?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

This will manually fork the Reminder child if the current worker has a WorkerName of Worker0. The result is only 1 instance of the remNode in the cluster and not 4.

```
if (process.env.WorkerName === "Worker0") {
   console.log(`${process.env.WorkerName} forking ReminderNode...`)
   remNodeProcess = childProcess.fork('./background_workers/remNode.js')
      .on('message', msg => {
         logMsg(msg)
      });
}
```